# i am trying to make small database with java+sqlite which accept input from user and save recored here is my code giving error

Tags: java, sqlite

> error  java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "-": syntax error)`

```
btnSave = new JButton("SAVE");
btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
 try{
    String query=" insert into Accounts(id,name,f_name,Address,P-address)values(?,?,?,?,?) ";
    PreparedStatement pst=connect.prepareStatement(query);
    pst.setString(1,txtid.getText());
    pst.setString(2,txtename.getText());
    pst.setString(3,txtfname.getText());
    pst.setString(4,txtaddress.getText());
    pst.setString(5,txtpaddress.getText());
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data saved");
 } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`P-address` has to be quoted with `"`, `[]` or backticks:

```
insert into Accounts([id],[name],[f_name],[Address],[P-address])values(?,?,?,?,?)
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a3dd5/1/0)**</kbd>

You could also consider changing `-` to `_` (underscore). So you don't need to quote anything.